# How to check all groups in an OU have enabled members

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to separate all the groups in an OU into two group. one that has enabled members and one that has no enabled members. Is there any easy way to do this?

I currently use:

```
$results = foreach ($OU in $OUs) {
    get-adgroup -SearchBase $OU -filter {Name -like '*'} -properties CanonicalName,CN,Description,ManagedBy,member,memberof,members |
        select CanonicalName,CN,Description,ManagedBy,member,memberof,members
}
```

to grab everything but I dont know how to then segregate them by their members.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can use Get-Aduser to search a specific OU. Then you can use a conditional statement to splice the active and inactive users.

Comment: the simplest way [to me] would be to use `$Results.Where({$_.Enabled})` to build a 2nd list that has the enabled accounts and do the same with `-not $_.Enabled` to get the disabled accounts into a 3rd list. that requires filtering the accounts twice, but otta be fast enuf as long as the number of accounts is not _huge_. [*grin*]

Comment: Are you looking for groups with absolutely no active users and then some groups with maybe some active users but also disabled users.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Would that still work if I am not trying to see if the groups themselvs are enabled or disabled, but the members of those groups are enabled or disabled?

Comment: @I.TDelinquent I am looking to seperate it by groups with no active users and groups with any active users.

Comment: @I.TDelinquent - your `$Results` collection should contain only _user objects_, so it looks like the result would be for users only. **_you will need to add the `.Enabled` property to your `Select-Object` list, tho. [*grin*]